# How to make widget without '?' and 'required'

Tags: flutter, dart

so im working on company project and realize the widget doesn't need Key? and required costructor, and when i try to make it like that it occur red underline.

> my project i want to remove the required and '?'

[image]

> example of what i want

[image]

Comment: So basically you want to make height an optional field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should view like that:

```
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final double? height;
  final double width;
  final String title;
  final double margin;
  final Function() onPressed;
  const CustomButton ({
  Key? key,
  this.height,
  required this.width,
  required this.title,
  required this.margin,
  required this.onPressed,
  }) : super (key: key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the non-nullable state of your class, you have to pass an initial value for the `CustomButton` height property.

```
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final String title;
  final double margin;
  final Function() onPressed;
  const CustomButton ({
  Key? key,
  this.height = 100,
  required this.width,
  required this.title,
  required this.margin,
  required this.onPressed,
  }) : super (key: key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have probably defined height as final and that's why it is asking it.

define height as

```
double? height
```